# <h1>Classification: {{ content.field_classification.value }}</h1> not displaying

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

Hoping someone can assist me please.

I am trying to display the value of a custom field in a bootstrap sub theme

I have created my `node--testtype.html.twig` template and that seems to work.

I'm trying to just show the content of one field, the machine name is field_classification.

When I use `<h1>Classification: {{ content.field_classification.value }}</h1>` the Classification displays as expected, but the value of my field_classification doesn't.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please as thought I d copied the correct code from what I have read?

Comment: Means you are only getting an empty `<h1></h1>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ content }}` is a render array and does not have a `.value`, just use `{{ content.field_name }}`

You only need the `.value` when you want to print the raw values of an entity object like `node`, e.g. `{{ node.field_my_integer.value }}`